# Wondering whether I should just bail on using properties in python

Tags: python, properties, setter, getter

I have been trying to use properties instead of specific setters and getters in my app.  They seem more pythonic and generally make my code more readable.

More readable except for one issue:  Typos.

consider the following simple example (note, my properties actually do some processing even though the examples here just set or return a simple variable)

```
class GotNoClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        object.__init__(self)
        self.__a = None

    def __set_a(self, a):
        self.__a = a

    def __get_a(self):
        return self.__a

    paramName = property(__get_a, __set_a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    classy = GotNoClass()

    classy.paramName = 100
    print classy.paramName

    classy.paranName = 200
    print classy.paramName

    #oops! Typo above! as seen by this line:
    print classy.paranName
```

The output, as anyone who reads a little closely will see, is:

```
100
100
200
```

Oops.  Shouldn't have been except for the fact that I made a typo - I wrote paranName (two n's) instead of paramName.

This is easy to debug in this simple example, but it has been hurting me in my larger project.  Since python happily creates a new variable when I accidentally meant to use a property, I get subtle errors in my code.  Errors that I am finding hard to track down at times.  Even worse, I once used the same typo twice (once as I was setting and later once as I was getting) so my code appeared to be working but much later, when a different branch of code finally tried to access this property (correctly) I got the wrong value - but it took me several days before I realized that my results were just a bit off.

Now that I know that this is an issue, I am spending more time closely reading my code, but ideally I would have a way to catch this situation automatically - if I miss just one I can introduce an error that does not show up until a fair bit of time has passed...

So I am wondering, should I just switch to using good old setters and getters?  Or is there some neat way to avoid this situation?  Do people just rely on themselves to catch these errors manually?  Alas I am not a professional programmer, just someone trying to get some stuff done here at work and I don't really know the best way to approach this.

Thanks.

P.S.
I understand that this is also one of the benefits of Python and I am not complaining about that.  Just wondering whether I would be better off using explicit setters and getters.

Comment: The same thing happens for simple attributes, not to mention local variables.  It's a direct side-effect of the design of the language and trying to "fix" it will generally cause bigger problems.  I've never found it to be much of an issue, though.

Comment: This is absolutely true and after I posted I thought about it a bit more.  I think the reason it is happening more is that I am relying on properties so much now (vs. my old setters and getters) and so am more likely to run into an error like that. The trick will be to just minimize the issue as much as possible and be more careful.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a static analysis tool? [Here is a great thread about them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470/are-there-any-static-analysis-tools-for-python)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your code works, you could try using [slots](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots). You'll get an AttributeError exception thrown when you try to assign something that's not in slots then, which will make such typo's more obvious.

Comment: Wow. Slots are very very interesting (and new to me). I will definitely be implementing them as part of my app, but not to solve this issue. For this it seems as though it might be an abuse of their intended purpose (which, I gather, is to reduce memory footprints of objects that are likely to be instanced very many times).    One thing I am considering, though, is to temporarily use them during development and then shut them off once I have completed my code - that way they will keep me honest now but not actually be in use (or abuse?) once my app is complete.

Comment: On second thought, looking at some of the unintended consequences of using __slots__, I won't be implementing them even during development.  Still very cool to learn about though.

Answer (score 0):

There are times when compile-time checking really saves time. You seem to have identified one such case. By accident rather than careful choice I use getters and setters, and am happy ;-)